# How to install Heroku AddOn

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, spring-roo

I am trying to deploy spring roo application on heroku... I m following this link:
https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-spring-roo

but i am stuck at this statement: **Add the Heroku add-on**

As they are saying:: To install the plugin run the following from the Roo shell:

> ***~.web roo> addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName net.stsmedia.roo.addon.heroku***

The error, I got is:

> Could not find specified bundle with symbolic name:
>   net.stsmedia.roo.addon.heroku

I dont find any material to solve this out.I Badly need Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used `addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB` to know if heroku is available for installing, but it isn't. So to install it you should use the OSGi command `osgi start`

The steps you should follow are:

1. Download heroku addon jar
2. Install and activate it with `osgi start --url file://...`

Comment: Hey.. can u tell me where should i download that heroku addon from?? Is this what u want to tell me: https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql

Comment: I don't know heroku addon, you should contact with project developers to request them where is the JAR